# Can't bind to 'cacheSrc' since it isn't a known property of 'img'

Tags: angular, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I'm unable to use cacheSrc even if I downloaded and added the needed dependencies. I also followed the instructions from this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-cache-src)

this is my img tag

```
<img cacheSrc="{{photo_url}}"/>
```

It seems {{}} binding is not supported.
How then can I bind it in a different way?

Comment: need more code or explanation in understanding

Comment: It seems that cacheSrc does not support this way of data binding {{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when one uses lazy loading.

To remove the error, add the `.forRoot()` to the module.

Then add it also to the imports and exports of your .module.ts file (like home.module.ts)

A more comprehensive answer can be found here: [lazyloading with ionic-image-loader](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader-example/blob/master/src/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you install it properly? You need to run the following:

```
  npm install --save ionic-cache-src @ionic/storage --save
```

You also need to import it in the module you're using it in.

```
    imports: [
        ...
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        IonicCacheSrcModule
    ],
```

If so, it may not be supported.

Comment: Sad, is there any way to bind data other than this ->> {{}}?

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
<img [cacheSrc]="photo_url"/>
```

photo_url is input for the `cacheSrc` so thereby binding the input value to the tag.

> Dynamiclly add url

```
 let paths: string[] = [];

    constructor(private _cacheSrv: CacheSrcService) {
        let images = [
            'http://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-500kb.png'
            'http://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-png-image-1mb.png'
            'http://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg'
        ];

        // Use cache() for one resource
        this._cacheSrv.cacheAll(images)
            .subscribe(cacheItems => {
                this.paths = cacheItems.map(item => item.path);
            });
```

> HTML

```
<img *ngFor="let path of paths" [cacheSrc]="path"/>
```

Comment: <img [cacheSrc]="imagepath/123.jpgl"/>works, but I need the image to load a url dynamically not me adding a specific url while <img [cacheSrc]="photo_url"/> wont work(referencing a value from a ts file)

Comment: how are you setting the photo_url can you update the TS part aswell ??

Comment: It was already set up that way. photo_url = this.authService.photo_url;

Comment: It didn't  work, I guess ithas something to do with ionic and angular

Comment: Aiyoo, it was my fault. I didn't take to account that I had lazy loaded modules. See my answer below :)